# Pundit Scope Involving Belongs_To Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I have a Pundit policy for the `Entity` model and I'm trying to implement a scope. I have the following models:

```
Entity
  belongs_to :project

Project
  has_many :entities
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :account_users, through: :assignments, dependent: :destroy

Assignment
  belongs_to :account_user
  belongs_to :project
```

Project has a field, `access_type`, that can be: Unlimited, Partial, Admin_Only

When a project's access_type is Partial, an admin can assign users to the project, allowing them access (via the `assignments` join table).

How can I write a Pundit Scope to allow a non-admin user to see only those entities where at least one of the following criteria are met:

- The entity is not assigned to a project (`project.nil?`)
- The entity is assigned to a project with `access_type: unlimited` (this is an enum, so `project.unlimited_access?` also works)
- The entity is assigned to a project with `access_type: partial` AND the user has been given access to the entity's project via an `assignment`

Here is the policy as it currently stands (the other methods are working correctly, I'm just having trouble creating the scope):

```
class EntityPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      if @account_user.user.admin?
        # If overall app admin then allow access
        scope.all
      elsif @account_user.admin?
        # If the user is an admin in this account then allow access
        scope.all
      else
        # If project is nil OR does not limit access OR (it allows partial access AND this user is permissioned for this project) then allow access
        # scope.includes(:project).where(project: nil).or(scope.where(project: { access_type: "unlimited" })).or(scope.where(project: {access_type: "partial", id: @account_user.project_ids}))
      end   
    end
  end

  attr_reader :user, :project

  def initialize(user, entity)
    # the "user" being passed in is actually a UserContext, see UserContext in app/models
    @account_user = user.account.account_users.find_by(user: user.user)
    @entity = entity
    @project = entity.project
  end

  def index?
    true
  end

    def show?
        if @account_user.user.admin?
            # If overall app admin then allow access
            true
        elsif @project.nil?
            # If the entity is not assigned to a project then allow access
            true
        elsif @project.unlimited_access?
            # If project does not limit access then allow access
            true
        elsif @account_user.admin?
            # If the user is an admin in this account then allow access
            true
        elsif @project.partial_access? && @account_user.projects.include?(project)
            true
        else
            false
        end
    end

    def new?
        true
    end

    def create?
        new?
    end

    def edit?
        if @account_user.user.admin?
            # If overall app admin then allow access
            true
        elsif @project.nil?
            # If the entity is not assigned to a project then allow access
            true
        elsif @project.unlimited_access?
            # If project does not limit access then allow access
            true
        elsif @account_user.admin?
            # If the user is an admin in this account then allow access
            true
        elsif @project.partial_access? && @account_user.projects.include?(project)
            true
        else
            false
        end
    end

    def update?
        edit?
    end

    def destroy?
        if @account_user.user.admin?
            # If overall app admin then allow access
            true
        elsif @project.nil?
            # If the entity is not assigned to a project then allow access
            true
        elsif @account_user.admin?
            # If the user is an admin in this account then allow access
            true
        else
            false
        end
    end
end

class UserContext
  attr_reader :user, :account

  def initialize(user, account)
    @user = user
    @account   = account
  end
end
```

**Edit:**

Here's the scope in my `ProjectPolicy`, which is working as far as determining what projects a user can see. The Entity scope needs to do basically the same thing but for the project's entities instead of for the project itself.

```
class ProjectPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      if @account_user.user.admin?
        # If overall app admin then allow access
        scope.all
      elsif @account_user.admin?
        # If the user is an admin in this account then allow access
        scope.all
      else
        # If project does not limit access or it allows partial access AND this user is permissioned for this project then allow access
        scope.where(access_type: :unlimited).or(scope.where(access_type: :partial, id: @account_user.project_ids))
      end   
    end
  end

  attr_reader :user, :project

  def initialize(user, project)
    # the "user" being passed in is actually a UserContext, see UserContext in app/models
    @account_user = user.account.account_users.find_by(user: user.user)
    @project = project
  end
```

**Edit 2:**

I got pretty close with this, however, it is not returning entities that have `project_id` of `nil` because the `joins` is eliminating any entities without a project assigned:

```
scope.joins(:project).where(project: nil)
.or(scope.joins(:project).where(projects: { access_type: :unlimited }))
.or(scope.joins(:project).where(projects: { access_type: :partial, id: @account_user.project_ids }))
```

So I then went with this, which seems to be working but feels less clean. Is there any way to combine this into a single query instead of combining the results of two? Is it bad to do it this way for now?

```
project_is_nil_ids = scope.where(project_id: nil).pluck(:id)
access_is_allowed_ids = scope.joins(:project).where(projects: { access_type: :unlimited }).or(scope.joins(:project).where(projects: { access_type: :partial, id: @account_user.project_ids })).pluck(:id)
scope.where(id: project_is_nil_ids + access_is_allowed_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that you need to implement ProjectPolicy instead of EntityPolicy (may be I am wrong). I wrote it according to my understanding.

```
class ProjectPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      if @user.admin? || @account_user.admin?
        scope.all
      else
        scope.visible_by_user(@user.id)

        # in project.rb
        # scope :visible_by_user, ->(user_id) {
        #   left_joins(:entities, :account_users).where(
        #     """
        #       projects.access_type = 'unlimited' OR
        #       entities.id IS NULL OR
        #       (projects.access_type = 'partial' AND account_users.user_id = :user_id)
        #     """, user_id: user_id
        #   )
        # }
      end
    end
  end

  attr_reader :user, :project

  def initialize(user_context, project)
    @user = user_context.user
    @account = user_context.account
    @account_user = @account.account_users.find_by(user: user)
    @record = project
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a separate policy for projects that is working well. The scope for projects also works (I've added it above). I basically need a scope for entities that is the same as the project scope but for that project's entities instead of for the project itself. The include/join is what's throwing me off!